# Semantic-UI "three inline fields" with dropdown

Tags: html, css, field, inline, semantic-ui

I'd like to have three inline dropdowns that do not stack on mobile and occupy all the space.

Here is the code I am currently using (RoR Code) :

```
<div class="three fields">

      <!-- birthdate day -->
      <div class="inline field">
        <%= select_day(nil, {prompt: 'Day', use_two_digit_numbers: true, field_name: 'birthdate_day', prefix: :user}, {class: 'ui fluid search dropdown'}) %>
      </div>

      <!-- birthdate month -->
      <div class="inline field">
        <%= select_month(nil, {prompt: 'Month', field_name: 'birthdate_month', prefix: :user}, {class: 'ui fluid search dropdown'}) %>
      </div>

      <!-- birthdate year -->
      <div class="inline field">
        <% min_year = Date.today.year - @sign_up_min_age %>
        <% max_year = Date.today.year - @sign_up_max_age %>
        <%= select_year(nil, {prompt: 'Year', start_year: min_year, end_year: max_year,
                        field_name: 'birthdate_year', prefix: :user}, {class: 'ui fluid search dropdown'}) %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

With `three fields` they use all the space, but get stack on mobile.
If I replace `three fields` by `inline fields` they do not use all the space.
I want something like `three inline fields` in fact.

I went through the documentation again and again and tested a lot of combination, I found nothing relevant.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an `equal width` grid instead of fields:

```
<div class="ui equal width grid">
  <div class="column">
    <!-- birthdate day -->
    <%= select_day(nil, {prompt: 'Day', use_two_digit_numbers: true, field_name: 'birthdate_day', prefix: :user}, {class: 'ui fluid search dropdown'}) %>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <!-- birthdate month -->
    <%= select_month(nil, {prompt: 'Month', field_name: 'birthdate_month', prefix: :user}, {class: 'ui fluid search dropdown'}) %>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <!-- birthdate year -->
    <% min_year = Date.today.year - @sign_up_min_age %>
    <% max_year = Date.today.year - @sign_up_max_age %>
    <%= select_year(nil, {prompt: 'Year', start_year: min_year, end_year: max_year, field_name: 'birthdate_year', prefix: :user}, {class: 'ui fluid search dropdown'}) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the `field` class on the `<div class = "column">` to have the bottom margin and it works.
I think it's a bit of a """""hack""""". Something like `three inline fields` or `equal inline fields` is more logical for me.
In any case, thank you very much.